# What happens to reputation points when this post is flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I came across the following post (refer screensnhot **#1**) in the question [How do I access Excel data source from an SSIS package deployed on a 64-bit server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448/how-do-i-access-excel-data-source-from-an-ssis-package-deployed-on-a-64-bit-serve)

In my view, I think this post doesn't truly represent the answer to the question. It is more like bypassing the error message reported in the question. Some can argue that is one way of solving the problem but the question does have a real answer without having to resort to this bypass method.

My questions are:

- Should this be a comment to the question itself or someone else's answer? I don't know who the OP was referring to so I think it can moved as a comment to the question itself.
- What happens to the reputation points if this post is moved as a comment?
- Most importantly, am I doing the right thing by flagging this?

[image: Post from the question]

Comment: I prefer seeing this sort of thing edited into the question itself. Even if it's not a good solution, it's helpful to know what the OP ended up doing, and comments are easily overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that instead of flagging *in this case* you could edit (or suggest an edit if you're under 2000 rep) to remove the "Thank you for your help" part, since it's irrelevant to the rest of the post.

That said, *in general*, I don't think that flagging would be wrong. A moderator reviewing your flag can decide whether to just remove the post entirely, convert it to a comment, or keep it around with or without an edit.

If the answer is removed, the reputation points awarded by the 2 upvotes will be removed next time the poster's rep is recalculated. That's typically a manual process, but global recalcs have happened before when a need arose.

Answer (score 1):

> Most importantly, am I doing the right thing by flagging this?

Yes, it's not an answer to the question and should have been a comment.

If the post (or "answer") is removed, the points are lost when the next rep-recalc occurs, AFAIK.

Comment: Note that the "answer" appears to be from the questioner in this case, reporting on the solution they used and saying that it worked. This is actually useful, and *almost* an answer, but would have been better added as an edit to the question text or such.